# Concatenate data from multiple fetch JS (RAWG API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm trying to build a website that displays games and details, I searched on google and found RAWG Api, they provide a public API to get more than 500k games data.

the result they provide is like this:

```
{
"count": 0,
"next": "http://example.com",
"previous": "http://example.com",
"results": [
{
"id": 0,
"slug": "string",
"name": "string",
"released": "2021-07-18",
"tba": true,
"background_image": "http://example.com",
"rating": 0,
"rating_top": 0,
"ratings": { },
"ratings_count": 0,
"reviews_text_count": "string",
"added": 0,
"added_by_status": { },
"metacritic": 0,
"playtime": 0,
"suggestions_count": 0,
"updated": "2021-07-18T11:39:53Z",
"esrb_rating": {},
"platforms": []
}
]
}
```

which means that the response is Limited to 20 results but they provide also a **next** link to fetch the rest of the data.

The problem is, I'm trying to get all the data at once and display it in one page, i'm using NextJs Typescript and that's the function I wrote

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
  let _games:games | any = []
  let url: string | null = `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=${key}`

  while(url !== ""){
     _games = [...await fetch(url)
                  .then(res => res.json())
                  .then(
                    data => {
                      if(data["next"] !== null){
                        return url = data["next"].toString()
                      }
                      else return url = null
                    }
                  ).then(res => res.json())]
  }

  return {
    props : {
      _games
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the data while the next property isn't null, and store it on the _games variable, but its not working, I'm getting an error at the second `.then(res => res.json())` saying that `res is not a function` but when I remove it, it returns `undefined`
Maybe its not the right thing to do... Anyways I would like to know how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recursive is better in this case

```js
let totalGames = []

async function getDataFromAPIWithRecursive(url) {
    if (!url) return totalGames

    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()

    totalGames = totalGames.concat(data.results)

    await getDataFromAPIWithRecursive(data["next"])
}

async function getStaticProps(key) {
    await getDataFromAPIWithRecursive(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=${key}`)

    return {
        props: {
            totalGames
        }
    };
}

getStaticProps("API_KEY")
```

Comment: apparently, this works, but i guess it takes too much time, and requests but i don't think there are other solutions

Comment: yeap, unfortunately, you will have to wait for requests at all times